# Lombok - constructor from parent's getter

Tags: java, constructor, lombok

I was wondering if there is a way, using Lombok, to declare a constructor with object, where constructor automatically populates variables by getting the values from passed object's getters, instead of having to pass all object's values as parameter. Something akin to:

```java
public Constructor1(Object o) {
    this.a = o.getA();
    this.b = o.getB();
    this.c = o.getC();
}
```

At the moment, I'm forced to pass all getters to the AllArgsConstructor by calling each getterm which looks ugly and unelegant to me:

```java
Constructor1(this.getA(), this.getB(), this.getC())
```

instead of being able to utilise simple

```java
Constructor1(this)
```

I'm aware that I am able to make my own constructor which will take object and populate variables with getter values, I was just wondering if there is a way to achieve this with simple Lombok annotation.

Comment: How should that work? `Object` does not have methods `getA()`, `getB()` or `getC()`.

Comment: object is just some other class with it's variables and lombok data. I named it Object for generalisation, when it in fact Object is a class of my own. something I imagine:
```public Constructor1(MyClass mc) { this.@allArgs = @mc.allGetters; }```
Alls variables in both classes are same, type and name-wise.

Comment: Note that you can always write the constructor by yourself.

Comment: @dan1st didn't read the last line

Comment: That sounds more like a use case for mapstruct than Lombok.

Comment: @jackar you could use some object mapper libraries like the github dozermapper